# Why I must declare field as "public" in abstract class to access it from derived classes?

Tags: c#, oop

I have CPU and human player so I decided to use abstract class in order to define common features. While their methods will differ, the field piecesToPlace will be the same for both.
I do not understand why it must be public, I thought that is like regular inheritance. I do not want this list to be public but it does not work otherwise.

```
abstract class Player
    {
        abstract public void Move(Piece p);
        abstract public void Place(Piece p);
        abstract public void TakeP(Piece p);

        List<Piece> piecesToPlace = new List<Piece>();

    }
```

Comment: Did you try [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx)?

Comment: [Look into the other access modifiers, namely `protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It doesn't work when you declare it as `Protected` ? If you don't specify anything, it is considered 'Private' by default

Comment: "Does not work" is not an error description. Post your problem, wewon't be able to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be public, but it does have to be internal, assuming the inherited class is in the same namespace, protected, or internal protected. An abstract class can define behavior as well as an interface. So, it still may want to hide implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

The default for class members is `private`, so unless you specify any other access modifier for the `piecesToPlace`, it will only be accessible inside the `Player` class.

You don't have to make it `public`, using `protected` would make it accessible to inheriting classes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are after the `protected` keyword, this will:

> Access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the
>   containing class.

Have a look here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simple , it depends on how you need it. If you define it public , for eg:

```
    class Base
    {
        abstract public void Print();
    }

    class Derived: Base
    {
         public override void Print()
         {}
    }

    Main()
    {
         Base base = new Derived();
         //its possible
         base.Print();
    }
```

if you define it as protected then base.Print is not possible to access(intellisense will not even show that such method exists). Since these methods can be only accessible from the derived class.